# How to post request and get response with retrofit 2?

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit, retrofit2

My service just use post method.

**in my code :**

***my ApiInterFace Class***

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @POST("srrvk")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<JoinAllAllowedInnoResponse> GETJOINALLOWEDINNOLIST(@Field("a") Integer lastOrderId, @Field("b") Integer rowCount,@Header("wkey") String wkey);

}
```

**and my getArrayList method is like**

```
  public void getJoinlist(Integer lastOrderId,Integer rowCount){
        showProgressDialog("Please Wait...");
        final String wkey = tinyDB.getString(Constant.wkey);
        Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "wkey          :" +wkey);
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<JoinAllAllowedInnoResponse> call = apiService.GETJOINALLOWEDINNOLIST(lastOrderId,rowCount,wkey);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JoinAllAllowedInnoResponse>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<JoinAllAllowedInnoResponse> call, Response<JoinAllAllowedInnoResponse> response) {
               hideProgressDialog();
               if (response.body() != null){
                   if(response.body().getEx() == null){
                       List<JoinAllAllowedInno> mJoinList = response.body().getJoinList();
                       mJoinAdapter.setJoinList(mJoinList);
                       if(mJoinList.size() == 0){
                           emptyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       }

                   }else {
                       getAlert(response.body().getEx());
                   }
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<JoinAllAllowedInnoResponse> call, Throwable t) {
               hideProgressDialog();
               Log.e(CLASS_NAME, t.toString());
           }
       });
    }
```

my question is when I put a breakpoint at response : noting happened ?

Where is the problem ? Any advice or sample code ?

**and my son is :**

My json uses Dynamic header

```
"ex": null,
    "c": [
        {
            "INNOID": 8,
            "SHORTDESC": "***************",
            "ORDERID": 1,
            "JOINEND": 1519074000000,
            "LONGDESC": "******************",
            "JOINSTART": 1514754000000,
            "DOCLINK": "*****************************",
            "TEASERVIDEO": "*****"
        },
        {
            "INNOID": 7,
            "SHORTDESC": "***********",
            "ORDERID": 2,
            "JOINEND": **********,
            "LONGDESC": "*****************",
            "JOINSTART": 1514790000000,
            "DOCLINK": "***********************",
            "TEASERVIDEO": "*******************"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887422/8089770

Comment: post your json for more reference

Comment: @VishvaDave I update my question

Comment: Your json is not valid check on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I checked it's valid json @VishvaDave

Answer (score 1):

First of all, enter your web service:
    public interface ApiInterface {

```
@POST("webservice/whatever")
```

Another alternative is to give it objects to work with:

```
Call<JsonElement> GETJOINALLOWEDINNOLIST(@Body YourRequestObject eg);
```

Then create 2 model classes. One for the request and the other for response. Use the same names as that in the JSON or alternative is to use a Jackson converter:
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

You'll figure it out there because I don't know what your key names are.
It will give you the java classes so just download them, put them in your model class folder. Then remove all the unnecessary serializable stuff and keep only the names and getters and setters.

Next, create your Retrofit API:

```
public class RetrofitClassExample{

private static Retrofit retrofit;

final private static String BASE_URL = "https://website.com/";

public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}

}
```

Then finally when calling,

```
ClassWhereYourCallIS classWhereYourCallIS= RetrofitClassExample.getClient().create(ClassWhereYourCallIS.class);

final Call<JsonElement> yourRequestObjectResponse = classWhereYourCallIS.GETJOINALLOWEDINNOLIST(yourRequestObject);

            yourRequestObjectResponse.GETJOINALLOWEDINNOLIST(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
String jsonString = response.body().getAsJsonObject().toString().trim();

                            JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(jsonString );

                            YourRequestObjectResponse yourRequestObjectResponse = new YourRequestObjectResponse();
                            JSONObject rp  = reader.getJSONObject("ex");
                            yourRequestObjectResponse.setSomeValue(rp.getString("keyName"));
}
```

> Not sure if this will help but here you go